# Is there a public Maven repository that contains spring-core 3 yet?

Tags: java, spring, maven-2

Is there a public Maven repository that contains spring-core 3 yet?

I can find 2.5.4 all day long but not 3.  If there answer is yes, please include the location in the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the milestones and release candidates from [Spring's Maven repository](http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/). The repository is difficult to browse, but the files are there, e.g. the [spring-core 3.0.0.RC1 pom](http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/springframework/spring-core/3.0.0.RC1/spring-core-3.0.0.RC1.pom)

Here is an example repository declaration and dependency:

```
<repositories>
 <repository>
  <id>springsource maven repo</id>
  <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
 </repository>
</repositories>

...
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.RC1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it exactly, thanks Rich!  I tried googling "spring maven repository" and before this question, there wasn't a single useful result.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question was asked, the [Spring Enterprise Bundle Repository](http://www.springsource.com/repository/app/) has been put online and is easier to browse.

Browse by Library, and then by Spring Framework, and you'll find what you're looking for.

```
<repository>  
  <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>  
  <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>  
  <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url> 
</repository>
...
<dependency>  
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
  <artifactId>org.springframework.core</artifactId>  
  <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version> 
</dependency>
```